# Group rows in fixed duration windows that satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as below. Consider df is indexed by timestamps as `dtype='datetime64[ns]'` i.e. `1970-01-01 00:00:27.603046999`. I am putting dummy timestamps here.

```
Timestamp    Address    Type    Arrival_Time   Time_Delta
0.1           2           A      0.25            0.15
0.4           3           B      0.43            0.03
0.9           1           B      1.20            0.20
1.3           1           A      1.39            0.09
1.5           3           A      1.64            0.14
1.7           3           B      1.87            0.17
2.0           3           A      2.09            0.09
2.1           1           B      2.44            0.34
```

- I have three unique "addresses" (1, 2,3).
- I have two unique "types" (A, B)

Now what I am trying to do two things in simple way (possibly using `pd.Grouper` and `pd.Groupby` functions in Panda).

1. I want to group rows by fixed bin of 1 duration (using timestamp values). Then in each 1sec bin, for each "address" find the mean and sum of "Time_delta" only if "Type" = A.
2. I want to group rows by fixed  bin of 1 duration (using timestamp values). Then in each bin, for each "address", find the mean and sum of Inter-Arrival Time*.

`IAT = Arrival Time (i) - Arrival Time (i-1)`

Note: If the timestamps duration/length is of 100 seconds, we should have exactly 100 rows in the output dataframe and six columns i.e. two (mean, sum) for each address.

> For Problem 1:

I tried the following code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': Timestamp, 'Address': Address, 
                   'Type': Type, 'Arrival_Time': Arrival_time, 'Time_Delta': Time_delta})
# Set index to Datetime
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[df.columns[3]]*10**9) # Convert timestamp into format
df = df.set_index(index) #  Set timestamp as index

df_1 = df[df.columns[2]].groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('1S'), df['Address']]).mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

which gives results:

```
Timestamp             1     2      3                          
1970-01-01 00:00:00  0.20  0.15  0.030
1970-01-01 00:00:01  0.09  0.00  0.155
1970-01-01 00:00:02  0.34  0.00  0.090
```

As you can see, it gives the mean Time_delta for each address in the 1S bin, But I want to add the second condition i.e. find mean for each address only if Type=A. I hope problem 1 is now clear.

> For Problem 2:
>   Its a bit complicated. I want to do get Mean IAT for each address in the same format (See below):

One possible way is to add an extra column to original df as df['IAT'], where

```
for in range (1, len(df))
    i = 0
    df['IAT'] = df['Arrival_Time'][i] - df['Arrival_Time'][i-1] i =
    i=i+1
```

Then apply the same above code to find mean of IAT for each address if Type=A.

> Actual Data

```
Timestamp                       Address               Type            Time Delta     Arrival Time                              
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  28:5a:ec:16:00:22     Control frame   0.000000    Nov 10, 2017 22:39:20.538561000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000287000  28:5a:ec:16:00:23      Data frame     0.000287   Nov 10, 2017 22:39:20.548121000 
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000896000  28:5a:ec:16:00:22     Control frame   0.000609   Nov 10, 2017 22:39:20.611256000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.001388000  28:5a:ec:16:00:21        Data frame    0.000492     Nov 10, 2017 22:39:20.321745000

                                     ...               ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact I had an assignment due by tomorrow.. I’ll edit my question to make it simpler. Secondly it can be done with even two single lines. I’ll add few  lines of code in a while. But that provides partial solution. May be someone who used those functions can help me..

Comment: Certainaly add your attempt and desired result.

Comment: @Parfait, any suggestions now?

Comment: Can you provide actual data sample with indexed *Timestamp*? It is unclear what units *Arrival_Time* or *Time_Delta* are in.